# Multivariate Interpolation and Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, interpolation

Suppose we have the data points $(w,x,y,z) \bmod 3$:

$$
(2, 0, 1, 1) \\
(1, 0, 2, 2) \\
(2, 2, 0, 0) \\
(0, 2, 2, 2)
$$

and the data points $(w,x,y,z) \bmod 5$:
$$
(3, 0, 1, 2) \\
(3, 0, 2, 1) \\
(2, 0, 3, 4) \\
(2, 0, 4, 3) \\
(1, 2, 0, 4) \\
(0, 2, 1, 2) \\
(0, 2, 2, 1) \\
(1, 2, 4, 0) \\
(3, 4, 0, 4) \\
(4, 4, 2, 3) \\
(4, 4, 3, 2) \\ 
(3, 4, 4, 0) \\
$$
and we wanted to compute $(w,x,y,z) \pmod {3 \times 5}$.

One approach is to directly compute $(w,x,y,z) \pmod {3 \times 5}$ using the point-wise application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem to the cross-product.

We note that $(x,y,z)$ are all distinct. So, we could formulate $w(x,y,z)$ as a multivariate polynomial evaluated at those coordinates.

I am thinking of using the method outlined in this MSE answer for the interpolation.

> Lagrange interpolation of multivariate polynomials, URL (version:
> 2020-08-11): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3787199
>
> *specifically* [A Simple Expression for Multivariate Lagrange Interpolation](https://evoq-eval.siam.org/Portals/0/Publications/SIURO/Vol1_Issue1/A_Simple_Expression_for_Multivariate.pdf?ver=2018-03-30-130233-050) by Kamron Saniee

**Question:** If we are just interested in a multivariate polynomial $w(x,y,z) \pmod {3 \times 5}$ and not the enumeration of the datapoints, could we do interpolation of $w(x,y,z) \pmod {3}$ and $w(x,y,z) \pmod {5}$ and then write down $w(x,y,z) \pmod{3 \times 5}$ in closed form using Chinese Remainder Theorem?